# Multi-Website, Multi-language switcher not working

Tags: multistore, ce-1.8.1.0, store-view, language

I have 3 websites(.com/, .com/en/ and .com/eu/), each has one store view.
And I created Website Switcher using this method.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270490/how-do-i-get-a-website-switcher-instead-of-store-switcher

```
<?php
$websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();

if (count($websites) > 1): ?>
<div class="website-switcher">
    <label for="select-website"><?php echo $this->__('Select Store:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-website" title="<?php echo $this->__('Select Store') ?>" onchange="location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($websites as $website): // print out each website name and code as a dropdown box item ?>
        <?php $_selected = $website->getCode() == Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getCode() ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $website->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl()?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($website->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now I want to add another language store view on .com/eu/.
However, language switcher is not working. I use the default language switcher.
The switcher shows up, but when I try to switch to the new store view, it redirects to the page of .com/ website.

How can I fix this?

Comment: please post screenshots of what have you done so far

Comment: what if you use the default language switcher, does it work?

Comment: I use the default language switcher. I only changed store switcher. But even if I use default store switcher, did not work.

Comment: May I ask why you are using the  "$website->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl()" - our language switcher uses GetCurrentUrl()

Comment: The code above is website switcher, not language switcher. And because I have multiple websites, I need to use "$website->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl()" . For language switcher, I also use getCurrentUrl()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that I forgot to reset on the admin config the base url on the website scope, instead of storeview scope.